# How to upload a document to Sql server database using linq to sql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, linq, linq-to-sql

I created a table in a DB, named Workflows that contain binary field named document, how to upload document to this field for later using....

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
RapidWorkflowDataContext context = new RapidWorkflowDataContext();
private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && ofd.FileName.Length > 0)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the schema of your `Workflows` table, it would be something like this:

```
Stream myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
if (myStream != null)
{
    using (myStream)
    {
        Workflows w = new Workflows();

        byte[] bytes = new byte[myStream.Length];
        myStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)myStream.Length);

        // change here to your actual field name
        w.FileData = bytes;

        // change here according to your context
        context.Workflows.Add(w);
        context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the code again. The `s` was supposed to be `myStream`

Comment: Thanks rhughes for ur help :)